# Does remote: true effect how parameters are sent to the controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters, ruby-on-rails-5

I have been struggling with this for the past two days now, and i'm stumped. I have a simple `form_tag` that submits with ajax using `remote: true` helper. I've been trying to access the value from the form in the controller using `params[:query]` but I keep getting `nil`.

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag queries_path, method: :get, remote: true do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :query %><br>
    <%= submit_tag 'Search', name: nil, class: 'submit' %>
<% end %>
```

Above: Seems to be pretty straight forward I believe.

**queries_controller.rb**

```
def index
    @search_term = params[:query] #value is nil

    gon.queries = Query.api_response(@search_term)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html
    end
  end
```

**application.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
    <%= Gon::Base.render_data %>
    <%= include_gon(:init => true) %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.19/api/sum().js"></script>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Righteous" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <%= render 'shared/nav' %>

  <body>
    <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
    <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>

    <%= yield %>

  </body>

</html>
```

**Console log**

```
Started GET "/queries" for 148.75.220.61 at 2018-08-29 01:26:01 +0000
Cannot render console from 148.75.220.61! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by QueriesController#index as HTML
  Rendering queries/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendered shared/_form.html.erb (1.3ms)
  Rendered queries/index.html.erb within layouts/application (6.9ms)
  Rendered shared/_nav.html.erb (1.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1180ms (Views: 113.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)


Started GET "/queries?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=egg&search=" for 148.75.220.61 at 2018-08-29 01:26:07 +0000
Cannot render console from 148.75.220.61! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by QueriesController#index as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "query"=>"egg", "search"=>""}
  Rendering queries/index.js.erb
  Rendered queries/index.js.erb (0.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1132ms (Views: 6.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I notice when the `remote: true` method helper isn't in the form i'm able to access the form's parameters in the controller, but this requires the page to load and a lose of the params. I feel like maybe i'm missing something. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can add a pry to the controller to see what values are in `params` - https://github.com/pry/pry

Comment: Just tried on one of my projects and `remote: true` with `method: :get` works just fine. Actually, on your logs, the second shows the parameter and it's processed as JS (which looks like a `remote: true` request but you say it's not remote), and the first one without the parameters looks like a simple html request (without `remote`). Also, there's another `search` parameter, does it come from the button? why are you setting `name: nil` on it?

Comment: im not sure where i got that whole `name: nil` lol. but its a simple remote form, i find it strange that i cant get the forms params with a remote: true on form. im really confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the log I see that there are 2 request on `index` action.

One without query parameter which I am sure you are hitting the `index` page without query. Another is with query param. You will always get `nil` with former one as because you are not passing anything in the request.

So ideally you should list all resources when search term is not found. So I would suggest solution similar to

```
def index
    @search_term = params[:query] #value is nil
    if @search_term.present?
      gon.queries = Query.api_response(@search_term)
    else
      gon.queries = {} # Or anything which makes sense when search term is not found
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html
    end
end
```